# Appending list of options but removing previous options

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

Hi im trying to append options in a select list dinamically depending on another select for example:

```
<select>
  <option value='firstValue'>firstValue</option>
  <option value='secondValue'>secondValue</option>
</select>

<select>
  // options appended from json depending
</select>
```

So im doing this

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

   if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {

      data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      data.races.map(function(race){
       $(race).appendTo(mySelect)
     })

   }
}
```

This works fine but I want the new options to replace the previous ones if and not stack up on the same select. I've tried doing using .html() but it only appends last value of the array I've also tried this:

```
    $(mySelect).find('option').remove().end().append($(raza))
```

But it does the same as before, just apppends only the last value of the array, can I get any help on how to accomplish this please? thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to clear out a  element is to set its length to zero.

Eg:

```
var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
select.length = 0;
```

That will remove all the elements in the list. Do this before looping through your data and adding the new items.